# SSIS - Recreating job caused it to lose access to configuration file

Tags: ssis

So, a little history on this issue. I had to deploy something into prod that had code from preprod, so I commented out the new line. But missed a character, which caused the job to fail on that night. Next night I fix the SQL in the SSIS job, the same error. No matter how many times I deploy, same error.
So, one of my coworkers decides to go into the integrations Catalog, delete the old catalog and redeploy everything. 
Next night, I get a new error that the environment variables are not set. So, I config the job, point it to what I assume is the correct environment variable. Same error. Tonight I realized that the environment variable that it was calling has been renumbered. So, I renamed the job, and recreated it manually pointing the envelope reference to the new environment variables. 
Now, when my job tries to connect, it tells me that that username fails to login.
I'm guessing that the issue is that when the config file was recreated, it was recreated minus the password. I'm trying to find out how to check and how to deploy my packages properly.

Answer (score 0):

So, we finally managed to fix the issue.
Turns out that by dropping the project and redeploying we lost the environment variables.
I had to configure the project to use the environment variable. I then had to go to each job step, under configure we also had to click the checkbox to use environment variables.